# The 'charCode' property of a keyup event should not be used. The value is meaningless

Tags: jquery, firebug

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="secrecy" name="secrecy" size="3" maxlengh="3" />Days
```

Jquery code:

```
$('#secrecy').keyup(function(){
alert("ok");    
});
```

Error message:

> The 'charCode' property of a keyup
>   event should not be used. The value is
>   meaningless.

The Jquery code doesn't work.When I input something into "secrecy", an alert doesn't come out.What's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you waiting to bind the event until the Dom is ready?

Something like this might help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#secrecy').keyup(function(){
    alert("ok");    
  });
});
```

Comment: .. I am having the same problem and my code is indeed inside `$(document).ready(function() {...});` and it still gives me the error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have the exact same problem here :( (Firefox 3.6.8, Ubuntu 10.04)

Answer (score 5):

I tested your code and didn't see the error you mentioned, could you provide code that reproduces this error?

I was thinking that it could just be the browser you are using...

> keyCode and charCode
>
> The two properties are keyCode and
>   charCode. Put (too) simply, keyCode
>   says something about the actual
>   keyboard key the user pressed, while
>   charCode gives the ASCII value of the
>   resulting character. These bits of
>   information need not be the same; for
>   instance, a lower case 'a' and an
>   upper case 'A' have the same keyCode,
>   because the user presses the same key,
>   but a different charCode because the
>   resulting character is different.
>
> Explorer and Opera do not support
>   charCode. However, they give the
>   character information in keyCode, but
>   only onkeypress. Onkeydown and -up
>   keyCode contains key information.

From [quirksmode site](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html), but I don't see you using either in your example code. Are you using them?

Comment: It is in Firefox in firebug. I don't believe i'm trying to use charCode or keyCode anyway intentionally in my code.

Answer (score 4):

That's not an error; it's a warning.

It's probably generated by code within jQuery that copies the properties of the event object to a wrapper that gets passed to your handler.

You should ignore it.

Comment: I can not ignore it. When I input something in “secrecy", an alert doesn't come out. The Jquery code doesn't work.

Comment: Then something else is wrong.  Are you running the code before the page is fully loaded?  Can you post a demo?

Answer (score 3):

change charCode -> XcharCode in source jquery-1.X.X.js and everything works OK

in the lastest version 1.4.4 there are "4" ocurrences...

Comment: Interesting. What is that doing exactly? :)

Answer (score 1):

i've a trouble too. I assign event to  but there not work!

$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#test ul").bind("keyup",function(){
        alert('Handler for .keyup() called.');
    });

})

Answer (score 1):

I followed Diego's advice and the warnings went away in Firebug.
Also saw the same advice here. http://api.jquery.com/keyup/#comment-108497941