# jquery charcode error

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

i have this simple form validation in jquery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = (function(){
  $("#register_form").validate({
   rules: {
      username: {
      required: true,
      minLength: 3
     },
     password: {
   required: true,
   minLegth: 3
     },
     password_2: {
   equalTo: "#password",
     }
  }
 });
});

</script>
```

If I digit a char in username I have this error in firefox javascript console (ver. 3.6.3):

"The 'charCode' property of a keyup event should not be used. The
value is meaningless."

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823951/the-charcode-property-of-a-keyup-event-should-not-be-used-the-value-is-meaning

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've always ignored this error...it's a result of [jQuery normalizing the event](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L469) (and assigning what you need to `event.which`), it causes no harm, and only Firebug seems to care.

Comment: @salvo76 - Be sure to close-out your questions by selecting answer that resolves your issue (or in this case, answers the question) via the check-mark to the left of the most helpful answer.  It helps the next guy finding this, and "closes" the question to remove it from the unanswered list.