# How to avoid this repetitive keyup error/warning?

Tags: jquery

I have a keyup function on a form input which executes every time a key is pushed and I get a warning in firebug that says:

```
The 'charCode' property of a keyup event should not be used. The value is meaningless.
```

I'm translating this as "the label is already hidden so your keyup event is doing nothing"

the thing is... I only need this keyup function to run once.

Quite simply the functionality is a label with a field tip ie 'Enter your email', hovering over a text input. On typing, the label disappears.

The problem is that my code tries to continue to hide this label every single time a key is pushed.

The html code I am using is:

```
<label for='inp_email'>enter your email</label>
<input id="inp_email" name="inp[email]" class="inp" />
```

the jquery is

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.inp').keyup(function(){

      $(this).prev('label').fadeOut('fast');

   });

});
```

So I thought it needs to do a check like:

```
 $('.inp').keyup(function(){

    $(this).prev('label:visible').fadeOut('fast');

 });
```

(Note: ':visible' in the selector.)

This doesn't work.

And I also tried:

```
 $('.inp').keyup(function(){

    $(this).prev('label').is(':visible').fadeOut('fast');

 });
```

But that error'd, so I don't seem to understand that .is function very well yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at your code: I'm not sure square brackets in IDs is good practice or even valid. Also you haven't specified a type for your input field? You should try appending new classes to your elements then add / remove these when you want to hide them. For example give it a class of hidden then search and modify based on this.

Comment: Thanks timothy. In my haste I wrote my code wrong above. I've corrected it - thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a check first, like this:

```
     if ($(this).prev('label').is(":visible"))
     {
        $(this).prev('label').fadeOut('fast');
     }
```

As stated in the [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/is/), "Unlike the other filtering methods, `.is()` does not create a new jQuery object." so you can't chain it.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/XswM2/) with a working version.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the .is() with chaining. That explains a lot.

Comment: @KeenLearner: Does the code work now though and you only get the warning once?

Comment: Sorry, even with the if statement above the warning still repeats on each keypress. I imagined your solution was exactly what I was looking for but didn't know how to do it but even still, it produces the repeating warning.

Comment: Even though this didn't solve the warning issue as it appears to be a slight bug with jquery of no importance, you did teach me how to do what I was aiming to do anyways so I've marked this as the correct answer.

Comment: @KeenLearner: Glad you got it sorted :) The keyup issue will occur for every keyup but as @Tomalak Geret'kal mentions, it's nothing to be concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is not related to your code not working.

It's just jQuery being silly. One day jQuery will fix it.

[Ignore it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823951/the-charcode-property-of-a-keyup-event-should-not-be-used-the-value-is-meaning/1823960#1823960)

Comment: Thanks for this. I realise its just a warning... I wasn't sure though if it is wasting resources for the end user or not.

Comment: @KeenLearner: If they have Firebug turned on, it might be. :)

Answer (score 0):

See: [The 'charCode' property of a keyup event should not be used. The value is meaningless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823951/the-charcode-property-of-a-keyup-event-should-not-be-used-the-value-is-meaning)

Basically it looks like you need to wait until the DOM is ready, with

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // stuff here

});
```

Comment: I will edit my post, because my functions are inside a $(document).ready(function(){} already...

Comment: In the question you linked to, the warning is _not_ related to that question's OP's actual problem. The real solution is this: [ignore it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823951/the-charcode-property-of-a-keyup-event-should-not-be-used-the-value-is-meaning/1823960#1823960). Perhaps a future version of jQuery will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
<label for="EmailInput" class="show-me">Enter your email</label>
<input id="EmailInput" class="email-input" type="text" />

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[type=text]').keyup(function() {

        var idValue = $(this).attr('id');

        var label = $('label[for="' + idValue + '"]');

        if ($(label).hasClass('hidden'))
        {
            $(label).removeClass('hidden');
        }
        else
        {
            $(label).addClass('hidden');
        }

    });
});
```

Can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/timothyclifford/5Y9Ws/2/

Comment: Cheers Timothy. I checked the example and it 'works', but the javascript warning still comes up in the firebug console.